# Angular Json Tree Directive not reloading when scope variable is updated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Just started coding using AngularJS. Currently I'm trying to display a JSON tree using the following plugin at github.com/awendland/angular-json-tree

**Current Situation:**
If the data is a static scope variable, the tree displays perfectly fine. 
[ScreenShot of the working scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVB4a.png)

**Problem**
The problem comes when I try to display the JSON tree after my AJAX data fetching. The directive variable gets updated with the new data but the tree structure does not seems to re compile and get back the structure.[ScreenShot of the Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3gtl.png)

I suspect its the angular tree directive that is not "refreshing".
Any gurus out there can aid a helping hand on this issue ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can't guess what going on without looking at code.

Comment: Including a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co) would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping the AJAX callback with a $scope.$watch function:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    // Your AJAX code here
}
```